# How do you register dill in copyreg to pickle a non pickable module?

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I have a setup where a python package I'm using is trying to pickle my code. A reduced example looks like

`constraint.py`

```
manifest = []
```

`constraint_loader.py`

```
import importlib

class constraint_loader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.constraints = importlib.import_module('constraint')
```

`test.py`

```
import pickle
import constraint_loader

pickle.dumps(constraint_loader.constraint_loader())
```

Running this fails with the error

```
% python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    pickle.dumps(constraint_loader.constraint_loader())
TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object
```

If I change my test to use `dill` instead it works.

`test.py`

```
import dill
import constraint_loader

dill.dumps(constraint_loader.constraint_loader())
```

I'm now trying to register, dill in `copyreg.pickle`

`constraint_loader.py`

```
import importlib
import copyreg
import dill
from types import ModuleType

class constraint_loader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.constraints = importlib.import_module('constraint')

copyreg.pickle(ModuleType, dill.dumps)
```

But running this gives me the error,

```
% python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    pickle.dumps(constraint_loader.constraint_loader())
_pickle.PicklingError: __reduce__ must return a string or tuple
```

How do I property register `dill` in `copyreg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what I tried, I could never get it to work. Instead a better workaround was to create a custom `__reduce__` method on my `constraint_loader` class.

`constraint_loader.py`

```
import importlib

class constraint_loader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.constraints = importlib.import_module('constraint')

    def __reduce__(self):
        return (self.__class__, (None,))
```